# Spring Integration - int-http:inbound-gateway

Tags: spring-integration

I have defined an int-http:inbound-gateway which has a request channel and a reply channel.  The request channel connects to a service activator which validates the message and returns a message response via its output channel.  How does one forward the validated message to another endpoint for further message processing?  Its like I need 2 output channels, one for the response and one for the message.

```
<int-http:inbound-gateway
    request-channel="requestChannel"
    reply-channel="responseChannel"
    supported-methods="POST"
    path="/message/hl7/{source}">
    <int-http:request-mapping
            consumes="application/json" produces="application/json"/>
    <int-http:header name="source" expression="#pathVariables.source"/>
</int-http:inbound-gateway>

<int:service-activator ref="HL7MessageEndpoint"
                       method="POST"
                       input-channel="requestChannel"
                       output-channel="responseChannel"/>

 <!-- need to send original message to jms if service activator validates successfully -->
```

Comment: can you post your work/code highlighting on what you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Change the reply channel to a `<publish-subscribe-channel/>`. That way, the reply will go back to the gateway and you can subscribe another component. You will probably need to add a task executor to the channel so the downstream flow doesn't run on the web container thread.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I don't think that will work because the reply channel contains an acknowledgement type of message, I need to process the original Message.

Comment: So make `requestChannel` pub/sub instead. Set `order="1"` on the service activator and `order="2"` on the second subscriber. That way, the second subscriber will only be called if the service activator completes normally. You must NOT return any result from the alternative flow.

Answer (score 0):

In your transformer add a flag if the message is valid 
      return MessageBuilder.withPayload(Dto).setHeader("ValidFlag", Dto.getValidFlag().toString())
            .build();
Add a router to determine if the message is valid
 Define in and out channels

```
`<channel id="requestInChannel"/>
<channel id="outputActivatorInChannel" />
<channel id="validatorInChannel"/>

<header-value-router input-channel="requestInChannel"
    header-name="validFalg" default-output-channel="validatorInChannel"
    resolution-required="false">
    <mapping value="false" channel="outputActivatorInChannel" />
    <mapping value="true" channel="validatorInChannel" />
</header-value-router>`
```

if the Message is valid make the in channel to two different activators

`<int:service-activator ref="OutputActibvator"
                       method="POST"
                       input-channel="validatorInChannel"
                       output-channel="responseChannel"/>`